# is it okay to use '5 minutes ago' to show time in web app using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, timezone

I ran into a problem of displaying times in different time zones. I am storing TIMESTAMP as UTC in mysql database.

Could displaying time like **5 minutes ago, yesterday, two days ago etc** can really solve the problem? and if it does solve how can I convert that UTC timestamp into javascript date?

Comment: ... and what *exactly* is this problem you are facing?  And what code is causing this problem?  You need to be much clearer and verbose in your description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date object which has a UTC method:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp